# backshifting of the "had to"

Tags: backshifting, perfect-constructions

There are many sites explaining the rules of backshifting in the reported speech but I am not able to find the one for backshifting of "had to".

> *I had to do it,* he said.

Which is the correct form in the reported speech:

> 1. *He said that he must have done it.*
> 2. *He said that he had had to do it.*
> 3. *He said that he had to do it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a sentence as short as that one presents no possible misunderstanding as to sequence of events, so you don't have to backshift. So number 3.

Another example:

> "I had to move all the furniture before the guys came to shampoo the carpet," Mary said.

reported speech:

> Mary said she had to move all the furniture before the guys came to shampoo the carpet.

Here, neither *had to* nor *came* is backshifted because there is no confusion over sequence of events.

Another reason is that *had to* is functioning as a modal verb expressing obligation. It is already the reported speech form of both *have to* and *must* (obligation). Further backshifting of *had to* would be rare, just like there is no further backshifting of *could*, which is already the backshifted form of *can*.

For general reference see [Reported speech: indirect speech
from English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech-indirect-speech) (Cambridge online)

and

[English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/reported-speech-backshift.htm)